# How do I combine predictions from two Tensorflow models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have several models trained on the same task, and I'm trying to combine them for better performance. Is there any way that I can combine their predictions using Keras? Let's say I have the following models, trained on ImageNet.

```
import tensorflow as tf

vggModel = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet')
mobileNet = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet')
```

How can these models be combined to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

You can average the prediction value of the two networks with a `tf.keras.layers.Average` layer. This is more easily done with the Functional API.

Here are two pre-trained models:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage import data

vggModel = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet')
mobileNet = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet')
```

Here's the model, combining (averaging) both output tensors:

```
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
vgg = vggModel(inp)
mob = mobileNet(inp)
mean_pred = tf.keras.layers.Average()([vgg, mob])

model = tf.keras.Model(inp, mean_pred)

model.build(input_shape=(1, 224, 224, 3))
```

Here's the input image and the decoder:

```
decode_func = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.decode_predictions

input_image = tf.image.resize(data.chelsea(), (224, 224))[None, ...] 

prediction = model(input_image/255) 

decode_func(prediction.numpy())
```

Let's look at the image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(input_image[0]/255)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here are the predicted classes from averaging the predictions:

```
[[('n02124075', 'Egyptian_cat', 0.3812103),
  ('n02123045', 'tabby', 0.060719665),
  ('n03788365', 'mosquito_net', 0.051269636),
  ('n02123159', 'tiger_cat', 0.020307815),
  ('n15075141', 'toilet_tissue', 0.014599041)]]
```